# Controlling the intersection of two surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, curves-and-surfaces

Let $F_1,F_2$ be two closed orientable surfaces embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with genus $2g_1, 2g_2$, respectively (edit: with $g_1, g_2 \geq 1$).  Is it possible to isotope around $F_1$ and $F_2$ so that $F_1 \cap F_2$ is a single curve that splits $F_1$ into two surfaces of genus $g_1$ and splits $F_2$ into two surfaces of genus $g_2$?

I would also be interested in the setting where we have any two closed $n$-manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and they intersect them in some $(n-1)$-manifold that splits both of the manifolds.  What can be said about the pieces?  Are there some obstructions to what can happen in this situation?

Comment: Certainly $F_i$ can be written as the gluing of two $g_i$ surfaces connected by a cylinder $C_i$ and it should not be difficult to make $C_1\cap C_2$ into a curve homeomorphic to a circle (two non crossing handles). Am I wrong here? In general I do not see how the topology of the intersection can have any effect on the global topology of the surface (which may be modified adding handles away from the intersection).

Comment: I think the answer is no.  For example, if $g_2=0$ you would be saying that a surface of even genus has to be an embedded connect-sum of two surfaces of half the genus, but if your $2g_1$-genus surface is knotted, that usually would not be possible.  I think you will have similar problems when $g_1>0$.

Comment: @RyanBudney Sorry I had in mind both genera nonzero - I also thought the answer should be no but I didn't know how to obstruct it.

Comment: I think that two Borromean surfaces of genus 3 are not disjointable in such way. Maybe someone more competent in 3 dim topology can actually prove it. Possibly, a genus 2 Hopf link surface is already a counterexample.